# What could be causing this mystery GCloud App Deploy error? (NodeJS, AppEngine. Standard Environment)

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build 6axxx...xxx9b status: FAILURE.

I'm trying to understand if I can use a NodeJS / Express server with Google Cloud App Engine, Standard Mode.  My application started out from an [Express-Generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) framework.  There is a single page app, and some function calls back to server via custom routes.  Nothing terribly crazy.

I set up repo, and $ `git clone https://gitlab.com/my_repo` into the GCloud shell. Test, test and retest using the sandbox (local development server.) Test url is of the form:  `https://8080-dot-xxxxxx-dot-devshell.appspot.com` Yipee.

Next step is hard deploy:  I start with $  `gcloud app create` followed by $ `gcloud app deploy` (had to make a side trip to ensure correct authorization and billing stuff is whole, etc...) . Website / server totally works as intended.  URL is of the form `https://my-custom-XYZ-website.appspot.com/`    Works great.

I can check the version at the [Google Cloud Platform -- App Engine -- Version console](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions) The output there shows me:

```
 Version: 20181120t103136
 Status: Deployed 
 Traffic Allocation: 100%
 Instances: 1 
 Runtime: Node10 
 Environment: Standard 
 Size: 748.8 KB
 Deployed: (Date/Time by me)
```

So that's the background. The problem is now I can no longer update the content. I can easily push code to the terminal interface, but the command $ `gcloud app deploy` fails for any sort of update / new version.  Sigh.

```
Log related info -- Build steps: 
Fetcher = successful

Builder = status, Step Failed
Builder Arguments   
--name=us.gcr.io/my-custom-XYZ-website/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:12xxxxxxa5a0 --directory=/workspace --destination=/srv --cache-repository=us.gcr.io/my-custom-XYZ-website/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d --cache --base=gcr.io/gae 
 runtimes/nodejs10:nodejs10_10_13_0_20181111_RC00
Directory   /workspace/

 "builder": Permission denied for "d71xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx88b5" from request "/v2/my-custom-XYZ-website/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d/node-cache/manifests/d71xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx88b5". : None
```

app.yaml

```
# [START runtime]
runtime: nodejs10
# [END runtime]

handlers:

  - url: /images
    static_dir: public/images
  - url: /javascript
    static_dir: public/javascript
  - url: /red-canoe
    static_dir: public/alt-content
  - url: /stylesheets
    static_dir: public/stylesheets

  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
    script: auto
```

Any idea on how to identify and correct what's wrong here?

Note: I did create another simple test product in node.js, and I can easily update the versions there. That test product had only a simple app.js with a simple `Hello World` response.  Version #2 had `Hello There, World` (okay, so yeah, not the worlds most robust test...).  But the version update, via $ `gcloud app deploy` worked just fine there.  I did note the version size on the Hello World app was around 245kb or so.

Comment: Check if the user account that you are using has permissions to deploy in that project. The role that you need to provide is [App Engine Admin](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/access-control#roles). If the permissions are right, try changing the name of the service or try deploying your changes to another service and see if it works.

Comment: @RubénC. This app does use Firebase for authentication.  When creating Firebase and / or Google Cloud App, we chose selections that made these two tools tied to the same project.  I suspect that is what is now causing troubles.  I'm guessing its better to just delete the existing project, then start anew with clearly defined and separate projects.  I doubt there is a way to surgically remove the Google Cloud App engine from the  integrated Firebase project (thereby preserving the auth api keys...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a whole lot of testing I think I figured out what is happening here.

The node.js application actually utilizes three different Google related components / tools.

- Google Firebase Authentication
- Google Sheets API, V4
- Google App Engine (Deployment)

When I'm created those components, the system prompts me to either create a new project or utilize an existing project.  I chose the exact same project for all three tools. I believe the fact that these were all tied together messed up the ability to perform updates to Google App Engine `vcloud app deploy`

The fix was to delete that three combo project, and create three separate projects

- MyProject_Sheets
- MyProject_Firebase_Auth
- MyProject_AppEngineDeploy

This works reliably.  All done.

And for anybody who may be interested in the Firebase / Sheets API stuff I did here, check out [this link.](https://dogfeatherdesign.com/friendly-secure-phone-directory-in-the-mobile-browser/)  I built an online phone directory, protected by login via mobile phone, with contact data stored on a private Google sheet.